# To identify the type of given set.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $$S=\{T:\mathbb R^{3}\to \mathbb R^{3}~|~T \text{ linear and }T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3),T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)\}$$
Then what can be said about $S$?Is it singleton,a finite set containing more than one element, a countable infinite set or an uncountable set? Please give me some start to think about this.

Comment: Hint: A linear map is uniquely determined by the way it acts on a basis. In this case you only know how the linear map acts on two elements of a basis but not on a third one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ are linearly independent. Take a third vector $v$ which is not a linear combination of them. Then, since $\dim\mathbb{R}^3=3$, $\{(1,0,1),(1,2,3),v\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For each $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, there is one and only one linear map $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into itself such that:

- $T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3)$;
- $T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)$;
- $T(v)=\lambda v$.

Therefore, your set is uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

Recall a linear map is uniquely determind by its action on a basis and $ (1,0,1), (1,2,3), (0,1,0)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thus each vector $ v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ gives a unique linear map in $S$, by setting $T(0,1,0):=v$. Moreover from what we said above this is a bijection.

So $S$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is uncountable.